# how to insert PostgreSQL result to a shell variable

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, variables, psql

I want to set all this syntax in variable

```
su -l postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE DATABASE graphite WITH OWNER graphite\""

CREATE DATABASE
```

so I wrote this

```
res=$(  su -l postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE DATABASE graphite WITH OWNER graphite\"" )

CREATE DATABASE
```

but **$res** is empty

```
echo $res
```

I also tried to add " " but without success.

How to insert the results of

```
su -l postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE DATABASE graphite WITH OWNER graphite\""
```

to a shell variable?

Comment: It works for me (PG v10 on Linux bash).

Comment: please show me what you do ( which syntax ? )

Comment: pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 9.2.13

Comment: do you run it as root?.. I mean could it be that you wait for password or smth else instead of reading stdout?..

Comment: As user root: `x=$(su -l postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE TABLE test (id integer)\"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking the resulting exit state works:

```
MacBook-Air:~ root# res=$(su -l vao -c "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin/psql -c \"CREATE DATABASE graphite\" -d so")
MacBook-Air:~ root# echo $?
0
MacBook-Air:~ root# res=$(su -l vao -c "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin/psql -c \"CREATE DATABASE graphite\" -d so")
ERROR:  database "graphite" already exists
MacBook-Air:~ root# echo $?
1
```

and the stdout shows as well:

```
MacBook-Air:~ root# echo $res
Timing is on. Pager usage is off. SET Time: 0.333 ms SET Time: 0.112 ms SET Time: 0.127 ms Time: 0.290 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more generic answer, but backticks (`) will put the results of any shell command into a variable:

```
$ foo=`psql -d postgres -c "select 'Hello'"`
$ echo $foo
?column? ---------- Hello (1 row)
```

That said, I'm curious why you would want the results of a `create database` command in a shell variable.  I'm sure there's a good reason, I just never would think to do such a thing.

Comment: var=`  su -l postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE DATABASE graphite WITH OWNER graphite\"" `    and echo$var , still give null value

Comment: Admittedly, I didn't do it with the `su -l postgres` but I did do a create database, and it returned the results info the variable.  Interesting.  Which Linux are you on?

Comment: backtick is old way - I think `$()` is preferred for bash nowadays. I'm not bash expert though...

Comment: @VaoTsun -- I had no idea -- I wasn't even familar with that syntax.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Hambone no worries - here are some reference:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082